# R: Error installing GWmodel package from source in R-4.1.1

Tags: r, install.packages

I am trying to install the package `GWmodel` from source following [this](https://gwr.maynoothuniversity.ie/) website. After running `install_github(lbb220/GWmodel/GWmodel)` I am receiving this error: `Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub: Line starting '<<<<<<< HEAD ...' is malformed!`

The reason I want to to install the package from source and not use the `install.packages("GWmodel")` is that I want to use `parallel.method = "cuda"`. In the [documentation](https://rdrr.io/cran/GWmodel/man/gwr.basic.html) it says:

*Requirements of using CUDA for high-performence computation in GWR functions:
To run GWR-CUDA (i.e. parallel.method is pecified as “cuda”) with gwr.basic , bw.gwr and gwr.model.selection, the following conditions are required:*

*There is at least one NVIDIA GPU supporting CUDA equipped on user's computer.
CUDA (>10.2) are installed with the environment variable 'CUDA_HOME' set properly.
The package should re-built from source. - For Linux user, 'GWmodelCUDA' will be automatically built if CUDA toolkit could be detected by the complier. - For Windows user, 'GWmodelCUDA.dll' and 'GWmodelCUDA.lib' will be automatically downloaded; however, we would recommend users to build the 'GWmodelCUDA' library manually to avoid some potentially unknown issues, and an 'CMakeLists.txt' file is provided for this procedure.
If any condition above is not satisfied, the GWR-CUDA will not work even though the “parallel.method” is specified as “cuda”.*

If I install it using `install.github()` I am getting the error I mentioned. I have installed the CUDA (>10.2) and I have set the environment variable 'CUDA_HOME' properly.

If I use the `install.packages("GWmodel")` I get no errors. I also tried to download GWmodel.zip and install from a local zip file, but the same error.

I have install `rtools` successfully (I tested it using the example [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools40.html))

I am using `R.Studio 1.4.1717`, `R 4.1.1` and `Windows 11`.

Any ideas how can I proceed?

I used `install_github("lbb220/GWmodel")` and although I don't receive the above error, still the installation cannot be done. I am getting the below message now:

```
** libs

*** arch - i386
"C:/rtools40/mingw32/bin/"g++ -std=gnu++11  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.1/library/Rcpp/include' -I'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.1/library/RcppArmadillo/include'     -ARMA_64BIT_WORD=1 -fopenmp   -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c GWmodel.cpp -o GWmodel.o
GWmodel.cpp: In function 'double sp_gcdist(double, double, double, double)':
GWmodel.cpp:764:29: error: 'DOUBLE_EPS' was not declared in this scope
     if (fabs(lat1 - lat2) < DOUBLE_EPS) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
GWmodel.cpp:764:29: note: suggested alternative: 'ENABLE_NLS'
     if (fabs(lat1 - lat2) < DOUBLE_EPS) {
                             ^~~~~~~~~~
                             ENABLE_NLS
GWmodel.cpp: In function 'void printMat(arma::mat)':
GWmodel.cpp:1165:16: warning: comparison of integer expressions of different signedness: 'const uword' {aka 'const unsigned int'} and 'int' [-Wsign-compare]
   if (m.n_rows < n)
       ~~~~~~~~~^~~
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-41~1.1/etc/i386/Makeconf:245: GWmodel.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'GWmodel'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.1/library/GWmodel'
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/GEOGRA~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpOwWBPs/file8f43609514d/GWmodel_2.2-0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try `install_github(lbb220/GWmodel)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not actually installing from the main repository. Try `install_github(lbb220/GWmodel)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you and tried these methods.

1. run R studio as administrator
2. change the access permissions of the R lib folder
3. download GWmodel package zip file and install packages by (/GWmodel_2.2-9.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")